# In MailKit How do I get the UniqueId for a message deleted from the OnMessageExpunged Event

Tags: mailkit, mimekit

Using Mailkit and monitoring the Inbox

I have the callback OnMessageExpunged registered on the Inbox so I can track messages deleted from the Inbox by external influences.

```
Inbox.MessageExpunged += OnMessageExpunged;
...
void OnMessageExpunged( object? sender, MessageEventArgs e )
{
...
}
```

When the event is fired, the MessageEventArgs has a field Uniqueid but it is **null**. It only has the message **index**.
I am tracking all the emails based on UniqueId because all the indexes change when a message is deleted hence I am sorta stuffed unless I rescan the entire Inbox on message deleted and look for any missing UniqueIds.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep consistent state with IMAP so that you can correctly map indexes to UIDs in your local cache.